# Construct a string who contain the hexValue of a binary array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to construct a string from a byte array (libcrypto++) but I have issues with '0' in order to connect to SQS in c++

The result is almost correct except some '0' go at the end of the string.

```
std::string shaDigest(const std::string &key = "") {    
        byte out[64] = {0};

        CryptoPP::SHA256().CalculateDigest(out, reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(key.c_str()), key.size());

        std::stringstream ss;
        std::string rep;
        for (int i  = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            ss << std::hex << static_cast<int>(out[i]);
        }
        ss >> rep;
        rep.erase(rep.begin()+64, rep.end());

        return rep;
    }
```

output:

```
correct : c46268185ea2227958f810a84dce4ade54abc4f42a03153ef720150a40e2e07b
mine    : c46268185ea2227958f810a84dce4ade54abc4f42a3153ef72015a40e2e07b00
                                                    ^          ^
```

*Edit:* I'm trying to do the same that `hashlib.sha256('').hexdigest()` in python does.

Comment: Instead of doing `>> rep`, I'd simply write `auto rep = ss.str();`. Dunno if that changes anything here, but I figure it could. Alternatively, look at `ss`'s `rdbuf` in a debugger. And while we're at it, `return ss.str().substr(0, 64);` looks even simpler than the erase.

Comment: And (sorry, I know this isn't Code Review, but couldn't help it :)) - if you change `out` to `std::array<byte, 64>`, you can use range-for (`for (byte b : out) ss << ... << b;`). This removes that one duplication of magic number "64".

Comment: It's seems that 0x0X byte is written as just "X". Try to use setw(2) and setfill('0').

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Thanks for your answer but I still have the same result. 
Btw I don't understand why the string is bigger than 64 character if I don't remove the end.

Comment: @Alexis hm, 64 bytes of raw information should actually expand to 128 bytes (characters) written in ascii form.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz with setw I still have wrong result but I will look in that direction thank you

Comment: ss << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::hex << static_cast<int>(out[i]); doesn't work?

Comment: @MarkShevchenko Yes it was that if you can post an answer I will validate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that indeed works, here's the solution with my suggestions incorporated.

```
std::string shaDigest(const std::string &key = "") {    
    std::array<byte, 64> out {};

    CryptoPP::SHA256().CalculateDigest(out.data(), reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(key.c_str()), key.size());

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
    for (byte b : out) {
        ss << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(b);
    }

    // I don't think `.substr(0,64)` is needed here;
    // hex ASCII form of 64-byte array should always have 128 characters
    return ss.str(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You correctly convert bytes in hexadecimal, and it works correctly as soon as the byte value is greater than 15. But below, the first hexa digit is a 0 and is not printed by default. The two absent 0 are for `0x03` -> `3` and `0x0a` -> `a`.

You should use :

```
    for (int i  = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        ss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(out[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the width for the integer numbers for the proper zero-padding of numbers with otherwise less than two hexadecimal digits. Note that you need to re-set the width before every number that is inserted into the stream.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main() {
    std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
    for (int i=0; i<0x11; i++) 
        std::cout << std::setw(2) << i << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
$ g++ test.cc && ./a.out
00
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
0a
0b
0c
0d
0e
0f
10
```

For reference:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill